# Best steps for upgrading a project with VS2008 and TFS version control up to VS2012?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, tfs

I'm looking to upgrade a VS2008 project that's currently on TFS2008 version control, with the eventual destination of VS2012.

One thing I'm wondering is whether it would be better to upgrade the project incrementally, to VS2010 then VS2012, or just go straight from VS2008 to VS2012?

The second question relates to versioning--I would like ideally to keep continuity in the versioning, mainly to make it easier to do a diff and see what's changed in the project files etc.  So should I keep the project linked while I upgrade the project?  Or should I unlink, upgrade, and then relink to the main trunk?

Would it be a bad idea to branch, upgrade the project on the branch, then merge back to the trunk?

My overall plan is to make a copy of the 2008 project, compile the project, run ILDASM on it, upgrade the project, resolve all compiler errors, then go through the [list of breaking changes for VB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc714070%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and try to track down and fix any "silent" changes, compile, run ILDASM on that, and do a diff to see what's actually changed in the CIL.

Answer (score 2):

VS2012 will connect properly to TFS 2008.  Just check out the files and open with VS2012.  You can then do a file compare to see what has changed and check in if everything is ok.   No need to go through VS2010.  VS2012 files are VS2010 compatible.